# Glassfish monitoring overhead

Tags: logging, glassfish, glassfish-3

### Main question

I have set monitoring on Glassfish 3.1.2 to HIGH for every available option. What is the overhead of the monitoring? What difference does it make performance-wise compared to LOW?

### Subquestion

Where is the statistics data stored? I don't see anything appearing in server.log, so how does Glassfish keep track of it? Is it in a file somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, turning on options to high results in about a ~7% performance degradation.  To reduce this overhead, you can turn all component monitoring to Low for an overall ~1% degradation, and only turn on high for specific modules (metrics) that help you troubleshoot or do historical analysis on.

GlassFish does not store statistics in a file. It's in memory.  To get historical analysis, use JMX-based management/monitoring tools or get Oracle Enterprise Manager.